# [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, html

I made a chat app, but this is just the server. I'm not very good at JS, but this code doesn't do what it's supposed to.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('app')

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return 'Chat app \
          <br> \
          <h1 id="p1">text<h1> \
          <input id="text2"> \
          <button onclick="chat()">Chat</button> \
          <script> \
          function chat(){ \
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text2"); \
          } \
          </script>'

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

It should replace p1 with the text of text2, but instead it replaces it with "[object HTMLInputElement]."

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text2")
```

will return a string version of element itself. It seems like you want the `value` of the element, which will be the user input:

```js
function chat(){
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML =   document.getElementById("text2").value;
}
```

```html
Chat app
<br>
<h1 id="p1">text<h1>
<input id="text2">
<button onclick="chat()">Chat</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text2").value
```